# Detecting Only Increasing Prometheus Metrics Over A Given Interval

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, grafana, metrics, grafana-alerts

Recently, I've experienced quite a few false positives in an existing Prometheus-based alert that has been difficult to nail down (that seemingly should be simple), so I thought I'd inquire to see if there was something obviously wrong with the query or the thought process behind it.

I have a Kafka consumer that handles reading from several different Kafka topics and an associated metric `kafka_consumergroup_lag` that stores a value for the expected lag for the consumer group itself. The metric exposes the following two important labels:

- `consumergroup` - The name of the consumer group
- `topic` - The name of the topic being consumed from

The typical pattern of lag (via a `sum(kafka_consumergroup_lag) by (consumergroup, topic)`) looks something like this:

[image]

However, if it began continually growing (without any decreases for a period of time), this could indicate a much larger problem.

**How can I construct a query to only detect increases for a given consumergroup-topic combination over the period of an hour?** I'd like to use this metric in conjunction with a Grafana-based alert to fire when this threshold is met (e.g. "Consumer Lag for $topic in $consumergroup has continually increased for an hour")

At present, I'm using something like the following which I thought would be sufficient, but I'm still seeing false positives being reported:

```
sum(increase(kafka_consumergroup_lag{consumergroup="my-consumer-group"}[1h])) by (consumergroup, topic) >= 3600
```

This has an associated alerting condition of:

- EVALUATE every `1m` for `5m` (since if it's already been increasing, we'd want to alert after 5 minutes)
- WHEN `last()` of `query(queryName, 5m, now)` is above `0`

This seems like a fairly *easy* thing to detect, but it has been quite a challenge to get it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those that encounter this in the future, I solved the issue by simply tracking a delta with the previous minute and an alerting threshold that would detect a positive value for a given period of time:

```
sum(
   kafka_consumergroup_lag{consumergroup="my-consumer-group"} - 
   kafka_consumergroup_lag{consumergroup="my-consumer-group"} offset 1m
) by (consumergroup, topic)
```

I'd imagine this could also be accomplished by the [`delta()`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#delta) function as well:

```
sum(
   delta(kafka_consumergroup_lag{consumergroup="my-consumer-group"}[1m])
) by (consumergroup, topic)
```

It would function as a "trend" where a positive value dictates an increase and a negative would correspond to a decrease. By using an alerting threshold of evaluating every minute for *n* minutes to determine if an alert should be fired.

Answer (score 2):

Query like this will return consumer-topic pairs, whose lag has not decreased once during last hour:

```
sum(increase(kafka_consumergroup_lag{consumergroup="my-consumer-group"}[1h])) by (consumergroup, topic) >= 3600
and sum by (consumergroup, topic) (resets(kafka_consumergroup_lag{consumergroup="my-consumer-group"}[1h])) == 0
```

Here function [`resets`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#resets) is used. It's designed to be used with counters, but since your gauge is somewhat counter like, it can be used too.

Comment: Hi @markalex! Thanks for the response, I tried using this against some know historical data and seemed to get some odd results with larger gaps.

Comment: One idea that I considered was to get do a sum of the current value with an offset of the same value a minute prior. This would cause positive values to indicate lag growth and negative to indicate lag decreasing. A positive value for some duration would be the alerting threshold. Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: Something like `sum(metric_name{ … } - metric_name{ … } offset 1m) by (consumergroup, topic)`

Comment: @RionWilliams, oh you are right. This query will produce strange result because of `increase`. It is designed to work with counters, not gauges. Use `delta` instead (it will produce similar result to `metric_name{ … } - metric_name{ … } offset 1h`). Otherwise this query should work.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with creating similar alert and I could not seem to properly use/trust existing PromQL functions like delta and increase. So like @Rion mentioned above, I came up with my own query. The query takes the difference between kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum now and a point in past (eg.30min) and checks if the consumer lag has increased by 5 folds in last 30 min. This is still not a fullproof solution as the lag may have gone down in the middle and come backup again but still should work when it stays only up.

```
(kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum{topic="your_topic", consumergroup="your_group"} - ignoring (topic, consumergroup) kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum{topic="your_topic", consumergroup="your_group"} offset 30m) - ignoring (topic, consumergroup) (5*kafka_consumergroup_lag_sum{topic="your_topic", consumergroup="your_group"} offset 30m)
```

This will return >0 if the lag has increased five fold else <0. Grafana alert can be set accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The following query can be used for alerting on Kafka consumer groups' lags, which weren't decreasing during the last hour:

```
(delta(kafka_consumergroup_lag[1h]) > 0)
  and
(resets(kafka_consumergroup_lag[1h]) == 0)
```

The query uses [resets](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#resets) and [delta](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/metricsql/#delta) functions for detecting increasing [time series](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyconcepts/#time-series), which didn't decrease during the last hour. The query also uses [`and` operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators).